# How to use two web service in android?

Tags: java, android

My application will be published in two different locations and we have a stand-alone server and database for both the two locations. I have hosted my web service on both two the server. I want to make a single APK for both locations. I have created one screen on which user will select his location and I store the value in session according to the selected location. Now I want to use a web service URL according to session value. How can I achieve this?

```
public class AppConfig {

    private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();

    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "Login";

    AppConfig appConfig = new AppConfig(_context.getApplicationContext());

    public static String BASE_URL = appConfig.apiDecider();

    public static String login = BASE_URL + "Login";

    public AppConfig(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public String apiDecider(){

        String lc = pref.getString("locationSession", null);

        //String lc = locationPref.getString("locationSession", null);

        String url = "";

        if (lc.equals("U") && lc != null) {

            url = "";

        } else if (lc.equals("S") && lc != null) {

            url = "";
        }

        return url;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not two different build flavors? But if you have got a way to decide which URL to use then whats the issue?

Comment: I want to manage single apk.

Comment: Simple create global variable for base URL and assign value according to user selected location.

Comment: i am doing the same thats why I have created function for assign a value

Comment: Then it's should work, what problem you are facing? Please mention exact issue in question.

Comment: I am calling my function apiDecider above and it is giving error or static

Comment: what is wrong with your code?

Comment: that's because you are trying to use non static things in static context. You are likely missing Java basics

Comment: can you please correct my code where I am doing mistake.

Comment: just use your `apiDecider()` method wherever you are trying to use `BASE_URL`